# How can I filter only some values from my nested XML in clojure?

Tags: xml, clojure

I have input XML which I have converted to clojure-map and can see all the values in one clojure map like this

But how can I filter certain values(mnAmountReceived) out of nested detail_D1 tags XML structure.

My XML is something like this, truncated for brevity:

```
<svResponse category="EVENT" environment="ENV910" pwd="asdfas" 
responseCreator="XAPI" role="ALL" session="7370710" token="asdfasf" 
type="realTimeEvent" user="sv" 
xmlns:rte="http://www.schemas.e1.oracle.com">
    <event>
        <header>
            <eventVersion>1.0</eventVersion>
            <type>EVENTOUT</type>
            <user>sv</user>
            <role>*ALL</role>
           </header>
        <body elementCount="3">
            <detail_D1>
                <szNextStatus>999</szNextStatus>
                <mnOrderLineNumber>1.000</mnOrderLineNumber>
                <mnAmountReceived>100</mnAmountReceived>
            </detail_D1>            
            <detail_D1>
                <szNextStatus>999</szNextStatus>
                <mnOrderLineNumber>2.000</mnOrderLineNumber>
                <mnAmountReceived>200</mnAmountReceived>
            </detail_D1>           
            <detail_D1>
                <szNextStatus>999</szNextStatus>
                <mnOrderLineNumber>3.000</mnOrderLineNumber>
                <mnAmountReceived>300</mnAmountReceived>
            </detail_D1>
        </body>
    </event>
</svResponse>
```

For eg: I want to filter mnAmountReceived and assign them to separate keys based on what the mnOrderLineNumber is under the  tag.

I am getting an xml which I convert to clojure map using the below functions

```
(xml/parse-str xml-str))
(defn clojurify-xml-map
[clj-xml]
(->> clj-xml
get-body
(map xml->map)
group-and-flattened-source-data))
```

I am trying to filter out the mnOrderLineNumber using the value 1.0 for eg so that I can get it's corresponding mnAmountReceived value

```
(defn filter-price-line [coll]
(filter #(#{1.0} (-> % :mnOrderLineNumber read-string)) coll)
)
```

I want to filter out mnAmountReceived and know with which mnOrderLineNumber it comes along with so that I can map it out in my response to proper fields for downstream systems.

Comment: Do you need to serialize back to XML?

Comment: you want a map of id to amount? e.g. { 1 100 2 200 3 300 }

Comment: mac No I don't want to serialize it back to xml but keep it a map.

@Carcigenicate for eg: these mnAmountReceived fields though are named alike in the XML actually are costs for different types of items... so when I process it I want to be able to say cost for part A is $ when mnOrderLineNumber is 1.0; cost of part B is $ when mnOrderLineNumber is 2.0 and so on... I am depending on mnOrderLineNumber as the key inorder to make sense of mnAmountReceived.

Comment: @pete23 yes something like that would help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you want to parse the XML and be able to treat each `detail_D1` as a map so that you can have line number and amount received together.  If that is the case one approach might be to use zippers to parse the data to Clojure data structures and then `filter`. Here is an example:

```
(ns so
  (:require [clojure.data.xml :as x]
            [clojure.data.zip.xml :as z]
            [clojure.zip :as zip]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn parse
  [file]
  (letfn [(parse-detail [z]
            {:next-status     (Integer/parseInt (z/xml1-> z :szNextStatus z/text))
             :line-number     (Double/parseDouble (z/xml1-> z :mnOrderLineNumber z/text))
             :amount-received (Integer/parseInt (z/xml1-> z :mnAmountReceived z/text))})]
    (with-open [r (io/reader file)]
      (let [zipper (->> r x/parse zip/xml-zip)]
        (z/xml-> zipper :svResponse :event :body :detail_D1 parse-detail)))))


(comment
  (parse "input.xml") =>
  ({:next-status 999 :line-number 1.0 :amount-received 100}
   {:next-status 999 :line-number 2.0 :amount-received 200}
   {:next-status 999 :line-number 3.0 :amount-received 300})

  (filter (comp #{1.0} :line-number) (parse "input.xml")) =>
  ({:next-status 999 :line-number 1.0 :amount-received 100})
  )
```

Comment: clojure.data.zip.xml, is this a valid clojure package currently? I added it to my project.clj but can't seem to be able to download it and hence I get error s on z/xml-> unresolved. Can you please point me to that package? 
These are the ones I am using currently 
                 ```


    [org.clojure/data.xml "0.0.8"]
    [org.clojure/data.zip "0.1.3"]
    [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
```

Comment: @Tabber You should not need `org.clojure/clojure-contrib` to get this example to work.  I used `[org.clojure/data.zip  "0.1.3"]` and `[org.clojure/data.xml "0.0.8"]`.  I also added a minimal repo [here](https://github.com/xfthhxk/clojure-xml-zippers).